# ConverseJS Openfire re-login issue (Bad Request 400)

Tags: http, openfire, strophe, converse.js

I am using openfire and converseJS in my chat application. I called `converse.initialize({ parameters})` at the beginning and chat works fine. But when I logout I called

```
_converse.api.user.logout();
```

And then when I login again I called  `converse.initialize({ parameters})` again.
That threw an error

**POST http://server.url:7070/http-bind/ 400 (Bad Request)**
error and hence could not login.

My full parameter list for the initialize method which is called at both occasions is as follows.

```
converse.initialize({
    bosh_service_url: url,//url passed from top
    jid:userId,//userId passed from top
    password: password,// password passed from top
    message_archiving:'always',
    keepalive: true,
    message_carbons: true,
    play_sounds: false,
    roster_groups: true,
    show_controlbox_by_default: false,
    xhr_user_search: false,
    auto_away: 900,
    auto_xa: 1800,
    auto_reconnect : true,
    auto_login: true,
    storage:'session',
    use_vcards:false,
    whitelisted_plugins: ['converse_plugin']
});
```

Let me know where it has gone wrong. Your help is really appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

`converse.initialize` should only be called once per page load.

If you want to log in again after having logged out, you can call `_converse.api.user.login()`.

Check the documentation here: https://conversejs.org/docs/html/developer_api.html#login

```
    this._converse.api.user.login({
        'jid': 'dummy@example.com',
        'password': 'secret'
    });
```